# Ubuntu 22.04 kernel updated to 6.0.0 without knowledge. How to find official version and downgrade?

Tags: kernel

I run ubuntu 22.04.1. I don't know why and how. I only noticed today that I'm running kernel 6.0.0. I can only guess what happened (linked question - how to find what/when triggered kernel upgrade?). I remember recently a notification popped up and opened some GUI software updater (Software Updater/Ubuntu Software/Software or something?). The updates listed iirc "software update" and "kde platform" (by which I also am puzzled). `apt` didn't list the updates that software installer showed. Right now `apt` shows nothing, while the "Software" app shows me update for "Gnome Application Platform version 43" and audacity `3.2.0`. I am afraid, that "Software" pulls updates from some development/bleeding edge/snapshot channel? I didn't upgrade kernel in any other way manually.

But now to the main point:

Where do I find currently recommended kernel version and possibly downgrade to it? I tried searching on ubuntu sites, on repositories and in the web, but didn't find anything. Some sites list `5.15`, some `5.17`, some `5.19`...

I would not bother othwerwise, but nvidia driver `515` and `525` stopped working (I also didn't notice until now) which forces me to rollback to latest working version.

Any ideas? (especially ideas of what could have happened and how to diagnose further)

neofetch output:

```
------------------ 
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Host: 81FL Lenovo ideapad 330-17ICH 
Kernel: 6.0.0-1007-oem 
Uptime: 29 mins 
Packages: 4093 (dpkg), 57 (flatpak), 28 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 42.5 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Yaru-dark 
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-8750H (12) @ 4.100GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile 
GPU: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] 
Memory: 5104MiB / 19879MiB
```

(GPU is nvidia 1050M iirc)

`apt` output for kernel:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep linux-image

linux-image-5.15.0-1021-intel-iotg/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-1021.26 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.15.0-1025-oracle/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-1025.31 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-56.62 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.15.0-56-lowlatency/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-56.62 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-6.0.0-1007-oem/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 6.0.0-1007.7 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0.56.54 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

---

**EDIT 1**
I found [this seemingly related issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443757/nvidia-driver-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04) but it's main point is making nvidia work while mine is to check what is the mainline kernel and If I am running some kind of bleeding edge.

---

**EDIT 2**
This is loosely related, but nvidia doesn't seem to work, because it doesn't support this kernel version yet. I found out from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444502/i2c-error-nvidia-gpu).

I also found, [that there are some packages with signatures for kernel `6.0.0-1007-oem`](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/jammy/restricted/proposed/linux-signatures-nvidia-6.0.0-1007-oem) but I don't know what they are, and they seem to be in a restricted channel.

Comment: It also happened to me - StarBook with Ubuntu 22.04.1. It now runs kernel 6.0.0-1010-oem and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

A history of kernels that were running on the machine can be found by:

- `last reboot`
- inspecting system logs
- checking access times of `/boot/vmlinuz-*` files
- displayed with `hardinfo` tool in the "Computer > Boots" tab.

When/why was kernel installed can be also investigated by one [one of these methods](https://askubuntu.com/a/1265489/1096597).

To boot using another kernel, <kbd>Shift</kbd> can be used while booting. Then an appropriate kernel can be selected in GRUB. [More info here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version). The kernel can also be selected from the "advanced" tab in GRUB

---

As to finding an "official" version — I still don't know. I don't know why kernel updated to 6.0.0-1007-oem while everywhere in the internet it says that the latest stable is 5.19 or something like that.