# Aften normal update and reboot, Ubuntu 22 fails to boot with drivers, how to fix?

Tags: nvidia, updates

Today I got lot of unusual looking updates to Ubuntu22 (with NVIDIA GT 630), similar as describe in other fresh [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475574/ubuntu-22-04-crazy-kernel-updates). After 4th round (typically 1-2 x to install and remove unused) of message to install updates/remove old, I cancelled it and rebooted. However, then boot failed somehow, and I was left with back screen after normal Ubuntu had listed some items loaded/started. Further, the starting logo was in low res during the load. I only managed to get to safe without driver for display or sound.

General error in distributed updates?

Should I wait for new updated and assume the situation is corrected, or what is the process to correct this?

Some details:

```
$ lsb_release -a  
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS  
Release:    22.04  
Codename:   jammy  

$ hostnamectl  
 Static hostname: ... 
       Icon name: computer-desktop  
         Chassis: desktop  
      Machine ID: ...  
         Boot ID: ...  
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS                
          Kernel: Linux 6.1.0-1015-oem  
    Architecture: x86-64  
 Hardware Vendor: System manufacturer  
  Hardware Model: System Product Name  
$   
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices  
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias :   pci:v000010DEd00001284sv....  
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation  
model    : GK208 [GeForce GT 630 Rev. 2]  
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free   recommended  
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free  
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free  
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free  
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free  
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free   builtin
```

Comment: What’s your kernel release number (`uname -r`) ? Does it end with `-generic` ? Most people (like me) use the `generic` kernel stack, but it seems that on 22.04 and 23.04 at least, `update-manager` suddenly wants to install other kernel stacks. Something seems to have gone wrong with Canonical’s update system…

Comment: I have not selected to go for anything else then generic, but is seems update-manager has changed something: $ uname -r    ->   
6.1.0-1015-oem

Comment: Indeed, it’s not a generic kernel. What’s the output of `apt list --installed 'linux-*'` ? You should probably delete all linux image, headers, modules, and Nvidia objects and signatures, that are not generic.

Comment: I posted in a comment below what I removed in my case where `lowlatency` and `oracle` stacks had been installed, I suppose you should adapt to the unrequested kernel stacks (i.e. at least `oem` from what you wrote) that got installed on your system, and reboot after all. Of course, make sure there’s at least one generic kernel remaining beforehand, or you may run into surprises… but it’s likely still there.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly the same situation here.
The solution that worked for me:
Explanation: there are no kernel modules installed. Please try installing the kernel headers

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

and then post the output of

```
dkms status
```

Reboot and good. Thanks to all who took the time to search and share.

Answer (score 2):

I too ran into problems with the new 6.1.0-1015-oem kernel.  I finally got it to work with the latest NVidia drivers (535.54.03) by following Tooster's advice in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1445292) post.
Basically, enter:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

while running the latest drivers from NVidia and using the new linux kernel. Reboot and profit.

Answer (score 1):

My system initially : GeForce GT 730 with 'nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended'.

Since the last Ubuntu upgrade I had an issue with booting. Hanging on 'Plymouth bootscreen'.
Purging the NVIDIA-drivers - as suggested elsewhere - solved that, but had some side effects.

As for a possible broken update : linux-firmware:all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.14 was published minutes ago. So I installed that.
Just prior to that I had installed the kernel headers as mentioned here earlier.

No issues now with booting.
My suspicions are on a broken Linux-update.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same error with updates you described and ended with a dysfunctional Nvidia driver, but with new kernel 6.1.0. Purging Nvidia, reinstalling, different versions: didn't work, then I applied this command:

> sudo dkms autoinstall

And reboot. Maybe it helps for your problem too. After this, I installed the Nvidia driver again (which I previously uninstalled), rebooted again, working great. Ubuntu 22.04.2, Kernel 6.1.0-1015-oem, Nvidia driver 535.